# deploy asp netcore 2.1 using web services

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-assembly

I have asp net core 2.1 and integrated web services too. All works fine in my development environment. But on live environment I have an error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 
  'System.ServiceModel.Primitives, Version=4.5.0.3
```

I installed System.ServiceModel 4.5.3 and it is included also in the runtime folder but it is not finding it. Why? What I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: I had a similar issue which i was referenced a local dll file. so it works fine when i'm testing. Then i removed the reference and installed the nuget of the library. Problem solved.

Comment: How install nuget package on production server ?

Comment: no need to install on production server. remove local references of the above library and install the same using nuget package manager from your local. Then push it to production server

Comment: Thanks Farshan, probably I am missing something but I installed it with nuget packet manager on my local dev environment

Comment: solved. Was deps.json file not correctly upgraded. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your Reference to the package is probably local. If you are using ReSharper it sometimes references Nuget packages locally (I also had similar experience).

check your references under `.csproj` file, if they are referenced locally remove them and reinstall using `Nuget Package Manager`. This needs to solve your issue.

Comment: I am not using ReSharper and I installed System.ServiceModel.Primitives using Nuget Package Manager on Visual Studio. The issue is on production server

Comment: did you check your *.csproj file?

Comment: solved. Was deps.json file not correctly upgraded. Thanks